429 response from the server when accessing the VirusTotal API
I have 2 functions virustotal_apiv3_scan and virustotal_apiv3_get. The first one accepts a list of links, sends a post request to the VirusTotal API to check the link, returns a dictionary key - link, link id value. The second function takes a dictionary and retrieves the result using a get API request. The free version of the API has limits of 4 links per minute and 500 links per day, I comply with this limit, but still catch <Response [429]>. Below are the code snippets and the function call:
import requests
import time
import math
import fake_useragent

def divide_list(input_list, divisor):
    # делит переданный список на подсписки по divisor элементов
    divided_list = []
    length = len(input_list)
    if length <= divisor:
        divided_list.append(input_list)
    else:
        num_parts = -(-length // divisor)
        for i in range(num_parts):
            start_index = i * divisor
            end_index = (i + 1) * divisor
            divided_list.append(input_list[start_index:end_index])
    return divided_list


def virustotal_apiv3_scan(api_keys, links):
    try:
        if len(api_keys) < math.ceil(len(links) / 250):
            print('Недостаточно API ключей!')
            print(f'Для обработки {len(links)} ссылок, необходимо минимум {math.ceil(len(links) / 250)} API ключей')
            raise SystemExit
        else:
            print(f'Программа запущена, примерное время выполнения {round(len(links) / 4 / 60, 2)} часов')
            print(f'Общее количество ссылок: {len(links)}')
        link_ids = {}
        link_blocks = divide_list(links, 250)  # размер одного блока - 250 ссылок
        for i, block in enumerate(link_blocks):
            count = 0
            api_key = api_keys[i]
            print(f'Текущий ключ API: {api_key}')
            for link in block:
                try:
                    # 1 отправить запрос на сканирование ссылки
                    user_agent = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
                    scan_url = "https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/urls"
                    payload = {"url": link}
                    headers = {
                        'User-Agent': user_agent,
                        "accept": "application/json",
                        "x-apikey": api_key,
                        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    }
                    response = requests.post(scan_url, data=payload, headers=headers)
                    time.sleep(1)
                    count += 1
                    if response.status_code == 200:
                        scan_result = response.json()
                        link_ids[link] = scan_result["data"]["id"].split('-')[1]  # получение id проверенной ссылки
                    else:
                        print(f'Программа вернула неожиданный {response.json()}')
                    if not count % 4:
                        print(f'Процент выполнения блока {round(100 * count / len(block), 2)}')
                        count = 0
                        time.sleep(60)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f'Возникла ошибка {e}, ссылка {link} не обработана')
    finally:
        print(f'Finally, links_ids{link_ids.items()}')
    return link_ids


def virustotal_apiv3_get(api_keys, links, links_ids):
    try:
        if len(api_keys) < math.ceil(len(links) / 250):
            print('Недостаточно API ключей!')
            print(f'Для обработки {len(links)} ссылок, необходимо минимум {math.ceil(len(links) / 250)} API ключей')
            raise SystemExit
        else:
            print(f'Программа запущена, примерное время выполнения {round(len(links) / 4 / 60, 2)} часов')
            print(f'Общее количество ссылок: {len(links)}')
        malicious_links = []  # список, содержащий вредоносные ссылки
        link_blocks = divide_list(links, 250)  # размер одного блока - 250 ссылок
        for i, block in enumerate(link_blocks):
            count = 0
            api_key = api_keys[i]
            print(f'Текущий ключ API: {api_key}')
            for link in block:
                try:
                    # 2 запросить результат сканирования
                    user_agent = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
                    result_url = f"https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/urls/{links_ids[link]}"
                    headers = {
                        'User-Agent': user_agent,
                        "accept": "application/json",
                        "x-apikey": api_key
                    }
                    response = requests.get(result_url, headers=headers)
                    count += 1
                    if response.status_code == 200:
                        result_data = response.json()
                        analysis_stats = result_data["data"]["attributes"]["last_analysis_stats"]

                        if analysis_stats["malicious"] > 0:
                            print(f'Вредоносная ссылка: {link} malicious {analysis_stats['malicious']}')
                            with open('result.txt', 'a') as wfile:
                                wfile.write(link + '\n')
                            malicious_links.append(link)
                        else:
                            print(
                                f'Ссылка возможно безопасна, analysis_stats["malicious"] = {analysis_stats["malicious"]}')
                    else:
                        print(f'Программа вернула неожиданный {response}')
                    if not count % 4:
                        print(f'Процент выполнения блока {round(100 * count / len(block), 2)}')
                        count = 0
                        time.sleep(60)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f'Возникла ошибка {e}, ссылка {link} не обработана')
    finally:
        print(f'Finally, malicious_links {malicious_links}')
        with open('finally.txt', 'w') as wfile:
            for link in malicious_links:
                wfile.write(link + '\n')
    return malicious_links

def main():
    with open('suspicious_links.txt', 'r') as rfile:
        links = [line.strip() for line in rfile]

>! api = ["fecb874b9a4a98c19f0dad810406975df83f64f8c5f60cdee36f5283d6c18eca"]

    ids = virustotal_apiv3_scan(api_keys=api, links=links)
    malicious_lst = virustotal_apiv3_get(api_keys=api, links=links, links_ids=ids)
    print("Вредоносные ссылки:", malicious_lst)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

When sending requests from the site, there is no such problem. This means it’s not a matter of exceeding the request limit. Also here is a list of errors codes
Ultimately, I expected response.status_code 200 and then get information from it
скриншот выполнения программы

The API might have different rate limits depending on where the requests come from.

When sending requests from the site, there is no such problem. It's unlikely you can exceed the rate limit when you're sending them interactively from that site.
